# How to write this sql query in model codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Please check my code described below. I want to use this query in CI model. How can I use this query in CI query builder in model.

```
$sql="SELECT `news`.`title`,`dep_table`.`dep_img`, `dep_table`.`dep_name`,`news`.`description`,`news`.`image`,(`news`.`created_at`) as created_at FROM  `news` JOIN `dep_table` on `news`.`dep_id` = `dep_table`.`dep_id`"; 
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned code in model.

```
public function getNewsData(){
    $this->db->select('news.title,dep_table.dep_img, dep_table.dep_name,news.description,news.image,news.created_at as created_at');
    $this->db->from('news');
    $this->db->join('dep_table', 'news.dep_id = dep_table.dep_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Let me know if it not works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->reset_query();       
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id ' );
$this->db->where('table1.id="1"'); // where conditions
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('news.title,news.description,news.image,dep_table.dep_img,dep_table.dep_name,news.created_at as created_at,news.dep_id,dep_table.dep_id');
$this->db->from('news');
$this->db->join('dep_table','dep_table.dep_id = news.dep_id');
$data = $this->db->get()->result();
return $data;
```

// try this